# In the MVVM design pattern, should models contain other models?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I don't think I have seen an example of this, but I also haven't read anywhere that explicitly states that it shouldn't be done. For example, let's say I have some user model with the usual stuff like first name last name etc:

```
public class UserModel
{
    private int userID;
    public int UserID
    {
        get { return userID; }
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }

    ...

}
```

If I were to strictly follow the MVVM pattern, would it be allowed to have, for example, a list of some other model

```
public class UserModel
{
    ...
    public List<SomeOtherModel> SomeList { get; set; }

}
```

or should models only have simple types?

Comment: Yes it's fine, it would be a hassle otherwise

Comment: It is perfectly fine, and quite common, to have a viewmodel contain collections.

Comment: Yes.  Probably what you are confused with is whether a VM should contain another VM?   Composite VMs makes no sense when exposing a child VM that the immediate V is not concerned with.  Plus it's a bit like putting excessive business logic in a VM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply, yes.

When doing MVVM you need to change your perspective a little. The definition of 'model' isn't the same as MVC, instead it encompasses everything that **isn't** the view and viewmodel. This means the 'model' is a data entity (i.e. POCO), it includes any services or controllers, it includes business logic, etc:

> **Model**
>
> The model in MVVM is an implementation of the application's domain model that includes a data model along with business and validation logic. Examples of model objects include repositories, business objects, data transfer objects (DTOs), Plain Old CLR Objects (POCOs), and generated entity and proxy objects.

Quoted from the MSDN article [*The MVVM Pattern*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)

So now that you've changed your perspective, if your question becomes *Should POCOs (DTOs) contain other POCOs?*, then the answer is still *yes*.

Comment: Contrary to MS's definition of a _best practice_, it is a best practice that a POCO is just that - _a class devoid of application layer; that contains **no business logic**_.  BL shouldn't go into VMs either.   Regardless of MVVM religion, there is always SOLID principles to go by

Comment: @MickyD Agreed, once a POCO has business logic in it then it becomes a business object.

Comment: After 8 hours of researching MVVM, other than my head exploding, I also feel that I want to move into the direction of your understanding of it.  I started with the question where validation (preventing duplicates in a collection) should go. Many do this in the VM, though I think this validation logic exists regardless of the V and its VM; I suppose you'd agree. Would you then also in a Model implement INotifyDataErrorInfo, or is that too view-related? I need it for a datagrid. Would I need it in both M and VM, as the datagrid you shouldn't bind straight to the Model?

Comment: Also, it somehow seems that there's 2 approaches to ViewModels: the first is that it is merely a helper to a specific view, almost aware of the view, replacing the code-behind in order to provide testability. This is how you see it, I guess. The second approach is to see the ViewModel as a wrapper around a Model, adding functionality to it. This goes against your understanding, right? You'd place functionality (say adding items to a todo list) in a Model mostly, right? Do you get what I'm trying to say?